Did I hurt my future financial worth by accepting a lower paying job?
I worked my way up to $80K in my industry, however the company I worked for abruptly shut down. I searched for new jobs for 1.5 months and finally found something that was a good fit. Except the pay is literally $20K under what I was making.... There is commission though, So if I can sell things, then I can make closer to around $80K.
What does this mean for my future income when searching for employment? I obviously would ask for around $80K again, given my years of experience. But will this even be achievable given the fact that I took a $60K job in a pinch?
I took the job because my mental health was suffering as a result of being unemployed. Additionally the job allows me to pay my bills and even save money each month. Lastly the new job is sales based, and I was managing sold work before. So this opportunity allows me to expand my skillset further. The only drawback is the financial setback...
Any advice would be greatly appreciated...

So make the commission... But if you took this for mental health then you should remember that.

Building up sales skills will mean that you will be better able to sell your skills to the next employer. You will gain experience in how to evaluate prospects, set your expectations of what you need to do to find a better employer, and the hunting processes for finding the elusive fantastic job.

You should negotiate any future salary based on your worth/value to the company, not your prior compensation

https://www.kalzumeus.com/2012/01/23/salary-negotiation/

The underlying assertion of this question is that a person is only entitled a salary based on what other employers were paying them. Is that what you believe?

No, for several reasons. First of all, you usually don't need to disclose your salary at previous jobs; you simply tell potential employers what salary you're looking for. If you do disclose your previous salary (e.g., perhaps that's the custom in your country, or a legal requirement), you can explain why you took that job despite the low salary. For example, you mentioned that it gave you an opportunity to expand your skillset, but there are many other valid reasons for taking a lower-paying job for a period of time. Lots of people do this at some point during their careers.
When you do look for another job, all that should matter is what your skillset commands in the market at that time. Know what your worth is, and what you're willing to accept. If someone offers you less, you can always say "no".

But if everybody is saying no, you may need to readjust your estimate of your worth. At some point, food and housing wins.

I was in a similar situation regarding salary.  Eventually, my 'long-term' salary caught up, but it took a while.  There are also things such as 401ks (US retirement accounts) that may never fully catch up.
In my region, the US, job salaries are often based off your current/past salaries, so it may affect future salaries, then again, it might not.

It does not mean anything for your financial future.  A surprising amount of your financial success is dictated by behavior more than salary.  If anything making a move based on your mental well being might improve your financial future.
Facts:
This job does not preclude you from securing a position that pays above 80 or even 100K in the future.
80K is nothing if you live a lifestyle of rugged consumerism.  That is new cars every 3 years, carrying credit card debt, and not contributing to your 401K.  Even if one does contribute, having investments that are conservative limits ones ability to grow wealth.
60K can be a lot if you live a frugal lifestyle.
If you are unhappy many seem to fill that void through rugged consumerism.  Its easier to be frugal if you are happy in your work and life.
Depending upon your commission schedule you could earn much more than 80K.

To a certain extent, YES, your career path choices do influence what your market value is for future job opportunities. Competitive employers absolutely do consider "career trajectory" when making decisions about hiring and compensation.
That said, is a ~20K drop in base salary an insurmountable set-back? Certainly not. Also, you mention that the position is sales-focused and has a commission. In many sales positions, commission can be a major or even the largest portion of the compensation.
The thing that's more important to consider than differences in compensation is whether you really want to do sales now and in the future. This job, at least temporarily, puts your career on a sales trajectory. If that's not what you want, you'll need to switch out of that before too long.
